# How do I combine two javascript string.join with comma separators?

Tags: javascript, textarea

Thanks to the help of Sigfried on here I was able to do a regex match on each line within a textarea and parse it out to a new textarea. Worked great but now I need to combine the two matches it pulls out with a comma in between, on each line.

So the following data from textarea (id=**input**):

```
1234567812345678
8765432187654321
```

becomes this an is placed in a textarea (id=**output**):

```
1234567812345678,123456
8765432187654321,876543
```

Currently the code parses 16 digits and puts it in **output2** and then parses the first 6 digits only which go into **output1**. Same string, two different outputs with different lengths. The actual data has a lot more than just 16 digits but I am trimming it down to 16 digits and then also 6 digits.

```
function trimit() {
    var str = "";
    str = document.getElementById("input").value;  
    var sixes = str.match(/(^......)/mg);
    var sixteens = str.match(/(^................)/mg);  
    document.getElementById("output1").value = sixes.join('\n');
    document.getElementById("output2").value = sixteens.join('\n');
}
```

I tried something simple like **sixteens.join + "," + sixes.join('\n');** and **sixteens.join('\n') + "," + sixes.join('\n');** but they failed. One insert a function message and the other only combined the last line.

When I did this I got the following:

```
1234567812345678
,123456
8765432187654321
,876543
```

OR

```
1234567812345678
8765432187654321,123456
876543
```

instead of my example above with the combined strings in one line, line by line.

Comment: As I'm understanding it, you're trying to concatenate a few strings together?  It sounds like you might way to do `sixteens.join('\n') + ',' + sixes.join('\n');` but I don't know if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped my example. I did use two pluses. I will edit my question. The issue is with the \n's. If I leave them in there it just merges two lists one below the other, instead of merging the two lists side by side separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand correctly but if you neef the final output to only have ',' , then why do you call join with '\n'. Try
sixteens.join(',') + "," + sixes.join(',');

, is the default separator of join anyways, so you can call join() also.

Comment: I will try that. I think the reason the join('\n') is in there is because the regex match is pulling from a list where each value is on a new line... and it is putting the list back in that format instead of having all of the values comma separated.